# Python - summarize try-except statement

Tags: python, except

I want to summarize the following code. What it should do is check if the variable in the calculation is assigned. If not, then the result will be zero. Because I have hundreds of calculations like these I don't want to repeat the try-except for every calculation.

How could I do that?

```
a = 1
b = 2
d = 3
f = 2

try:
    ab = a + b
except:
    ab = 0

try:    
    ac = a - c
except:
    ac = 0

try:    
    bg = b / g
except:
    ac = 0
```

Comment: What would the exception be?

Comment: If one variable is not assigned.

Comment: there must be a better way...

Comment: I mean a better way to structure your code instead of checking for exceptions, you should always know which variables are assigned IMHO

Comment: I totaly agree with you. It doesn't have to check for exceptions. Sorry for not being clear enough in my original post.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do here, but maybe rather than allowing some variables to be unassigned (is this in an interactive situation? why would variables not be assigned?), you could set them to `float('nan')`. Then any calculations involving the undefined values will propagate through as `nan`.

Comment: That is probably the best idea. I create a list of all my variables and loop through them if they have a value assigned or not. In case they have not I will set them to `float('nan')`. (Post it as a answer with some code and I will accept it as an answer)

Comment: How are you creating a list of all your variables and checking "if they have a value assigned or not"? If the variable isn't assigned, you can't put it in a list, loop over it, or check it.

Comment: More importantly: This is almost certainly an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please explain what you're actually trying to do, and why you think you want this, and I'll give you very good odds that we can explain how to solve your real problem in such a way that the apparent problem with exceptions never even arises.

Comment: @abarnert you are right. I figured I can't but a not assigned variable in a list.

Comment: @abarnert I guess you are right as well that it is a XY problem. My problem is that I have a long script and depending on the certain inputs some variables get assigned and some not. However later on in the script these variables are used anyway. The problem is then if they were not assigned earlier a value, the script obviously tells me "local variable 'var' referenced before assignment". Is it more clear now? And is it maybe better to close this question and I ask it new in a different way?

Comment: @user1738154: I'm not sure whether to create a new question, or edit this one. But either way, yes, you need to ask us the real problem you're trying to solve. The answer might be to pre-initialize all the variables at the top of the script, or to use a collection of values instead of a bunch of variables, or to fix the bugs that cause variables to not get assigned, or whatever, depending on the actual question.

Comment: @abarnert:I pre-initalized all the variables at the top of the script and that obviously solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Write a function to do it, using a `lambda` (a one-line function) to defer the evaluation of the variables in case one of them doesn't exist:

```
def call_with_default(func, default):
    try:
        return func()
    except NameError:   # for names that don't exist
        return default

ab = call_with_default(lambda: a+b, 0)
# etc.
```

You might benefit by using some sort of data structure (e.g. list or dictionary) to contain your values rather than storing them in individual variables; it's possible you could then use loops to do all these calculations instead of writing them all individually.

Comment: I was thinking about what you mention in the second paragraph too; tuples would fit nicely, at least for the given code.

Comment: Your first option works. However it is still a lot of coding for all the individual calculations. The problem with your second option is that the calculations differ from each time (sorry for not clarifying that in my original post).

Comment: @user1738154 There may be a solution using `lambda`, but I'm not sure if there's a way to find a solution as graceful as in Lisp.

Comment: Also, if the OP's exception comes "if one variable is not assigned", this doesn't help anything, because the attempt to call `add_default` will raise the exact same `NameError`, before you even get into the function.

Comment: @abarnert: Good point, for some reason I had in my head that it might just be some of them were `None`. If you are trying to do calculations on variables that might not even be defined, that just strengthens the case that you should be using a different data structure. Regardless, I've updated my function to use a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a bunch of variables that might not even be defined, you probably don't really have a bunch of variables.

For example, if you're trying to build an interactive interpreter, where the user can create new variables, don't try to save each user variable as a global variable of the same name (if for no other reason than safety—what happens if the user tries to create a variable named `main` and erases your `main` function?). Store a dictionary of user variables.

Once you do that, the solutions suggested by Alexey and kindall will work:

```
def add_default(first, second, default):
    try:
        return variables[first] + variables[second]
    except KeyError:
        return default

    variables['ab'] = add_default('a', 'b', 0)
```

If you really do need to mix in your code and user code at the same level, you *can* do it, by using `globals()` itself as your dictionary:

```
def add_default(first, second, default):
    try:
        return globals()[first] + globals()[second]
    except KeyError:
        return default

ab = add_default('a', 'b', 0)
```

However, using `globals` this way is almost always a sign that you've made a major design error earlier, and the right thing to do is back up until you find that error…

---

Meanwhile, from a comment:

> I create a list of all my variables and loop through them if they have a value assigned or not. In case they have not I will set them to float('nan').

There's no way to create a list of variables (except, of course, by referencing them by name off `globals()`). You can create a list of *values*, but that won't do you any good, because there are no values for the undefined variables.

This is yet another sign that what you probably want here is not a bunch of separate variables, but a dictionary.

In particular, you probably want a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
variables = collections.defaultdict(lambda: float('nan'))
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more generic case you may use lambdas (though not too graceful solution):

```
def lambda_default(func, default, *args):
    try:
        return func(*args)
    except:
        return default

abc = lambda_default(lambda x, y: x + y * z, 0, a, b, c)
```

In case you have some commonly used functions, you may wrap them into one more `def`, of course:

```
def add_default(first, second, default):
    return lambda_default(operator.add, 0, first, second)

ab = add_default(a, b, 0)
```

Comment: You don't need to write `lambda x, y: x + y`; just use [`operator.add`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.add).

Comment: Also, as with kindall's answer, this doesn't help the OP's actual problem. If `b` is not defined, `add_default(a, b, 0)` will raise a `NameError` without even calling `add_default`.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks, I've added operator.add to the second part and have made the first one more complicated to preserve generality.

Regarding the `NameError`. I think there's no way to hide `try-catch` completely even at runtime. Hopefully I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, the point is that what you (and kindall) have added doesn't help the OP at all. His original problem was that he got a `NameError` when using undefined variables, so he needed to add `try`/`except` to every single expression to handle that. With your proposed solution… he'll still get a `NameError` when using undefined variables, so he'll still need to add `try`/`except` to every single expression to handle that. So what does he gain?

Comment: Meanwhile, of course there's a way to get around this at runtime: reference the variables by name, and look them up in `globals`, as my answer shows. It's a very bad idea, but it's the only thing that can possibly help here.

Comment: … well, I suppose `eval`/`exec` could possibly help here, or a preprocessor, or all kinds of other things even worse than `globals`…